# Apache Flink - WordCount - NoResourceAvailableException

Tags: java, apache-flink

Installing (download & tar zxf) Apache Flink 1.11.1 and running:
`./bin/flink run examples/streaming/WordCount.jar` it show on the nice message after more less 5 min. the trying of submitting:

```
   Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Could not allocate the required slot within slot request timeout. Please make sure that the cluster has enough resources.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeWrapWithNoResourceAvailableException(DefaultScheduler.java:441)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:607)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591)
```

It's Flink default configuration.

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
```

## free -g

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             62           1          23           3          37          57
Swap:             7           0           7
```

are there some advices about: what is happened here?

Comment: Could verify that there are TaskExecutors registered at the JobManager? You should see this in the web UI or in the logs of the JobManager.

Comment: Logs info:
2020-10-07 17:11:25,233 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Allocated slot for 36ab206aecabb3dc5f45b77d3bf671fb.
2020-10-07 17:11:25,233 INFO  2020-10-07 17:11:25,236 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.DefaultJobLeaderService [] - Resolved JobManager address, beginning registration
2020-10-07 17:11:35,233 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.slot.TaskSlotTableImpl [] - Free slot TaskSlot(index:0, state:ALLOCATED, resource profile: ResourceProfile{cpuCores=1.0000000000000000, taskHeapMemory=843.600mb , taskOffHeapMemory=0 byttres

Comment: Could you share the complete logs for both processes with us?

Comment: sure, Khachatryan Roman - is from your team? I've sent him the complete logs.

Comment: Could you post the logs also here (unless they contain sensitive information)? This would give the community the opportunity to help as well.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_3TmDViltPS__tK3vhTpRHlOyMg37t4X/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for sharing the logs with us. From the logs it looks as if the `TaskExecutor` cannot establish a connection with the `JobMaster`. I tried the same with Flink 1.11.2 on my machine and it successfully executed the WordCount. Could you enable DEBUG logs in FLINK_HOME/conf/log4j.properties? Maybe they tell us what is going wrong. Moreover, you could increase `akka.ask.timeout: 60 s` in your `flink-conf.yaml` to give the registration a bit more time before slots are being freed.

Comment: with akka.ask.timeout: 60 - the some issue > WordCount.jar was canceled after 5 min. of starting. The job status has never changed from "Created".

Comment: with DEBUG>2020-10-19 13:20:51,911 DEBUG org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader [] - Unable to load the library org_apache_flink_shaded_netty4_netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_64', trying other loading mechanism.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no org_apache_flink_shaded_netty4_netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_64 in java.library.path

Comment: Could you share the complete debug logs with us @Alexander?

Comment: running WordCount with DEBUG:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z2MjVKys40klJhVNDKVBfxpWc2wOVrFr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Today I've successfully run Apache Flink v.1.10.2 on my cluster. It would be great to find a solution for Flink v.1.11.*. I tried with 1.11.1, 1.11.2 - was the same error about NoResourceAvailableException

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in Flink 1.11.3.
[Refer this link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-19237).