# Flink 1.13.2: NoResourceAvailableException

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

This is with Flink 1.13.2 running in Amazon's Kinesis Data Analytics Flink environment.

This application is running on Kafka topics. When the topics had smaller traffic volumes, this application ran fine, with larger volumes, I'm getting this error. How do I troubleshoot and tune and fix?

I see similar looking SO questions like this but that is clearly a separate issue in older versions of Flink:
[Apache Flink - WordCount - NoResourceAvailableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64252040/apache-flink-wordcount-noresourceavailableexception)

The exception trace is:

```
2021-12-30 18:16:45
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Could not acquire the minimum required resources.
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:346)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:632)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge$PendingRequest.failRequest(DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.java:535)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.cancelPendingRequests(DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.java:128)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.failPendingRequests(DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.java:362)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.notifyNotEnoughResourcesAvailable(DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.java:351)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.notifyNotEnoughResourcesAvailable(JobMaster.java:824)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor133.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:301)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:158)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Could not acquire the minimum required resources.
    ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I meet this problem and my solution is :
configure the file 'conf/flink-conf.yaml'

```
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 1
```

change to

```
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 30
```

this slots depend on how much running tasks

Answer (score 6):

From the perspective of the task error, it is just because there are no resources, which is different from the other problem mentioned in the feedback.

Maybe you can reduce the parallelism and have a try

Comment: What kind of resources? Nodes to scale to? RAM? CPU? Disk?

Comment: CPU and memory resources. Total resources = single TM resource * TM number

Answer (score 5):

The NoResourceAvailableException indicates that there are not enough task slots available to satisfy the running job. Either increase the number of slots per TaskManager or add additional TaskManager instances to the Flink cluster. Reducing the parallelism of the job as suggested by ChangLi might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, It come from because I submitted job by starting JobManager.
Please `./bin/start-cluster.sh`